# Failed to set remote offer sdp: Called with SDP without SDES crypto

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle, dtls

Trying to use Android application for WebRTC Based on APpRtcDemo. 
When connecting from Chrome 34 Everythings works fine, But When I use Chrome 35 for video call f got this error.

```
 onSetFailure: Failed to set remote offer sdp: Called with SDP without SDES crypto.
```

Here media constraints, which I'm trying to use

```
sdpMediaConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
sdpMediaConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "true"));        
sdpMediaConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "true"));
sdpMediaConstraints.optional.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"));
```

Here is Code setting remote description

```
    pc.setRemoteDescription(sdpObserver, new SessionDescription(
            SessionDescription.Type.OFFER, description.toString()));
```

Comment: it is likely that you are hitting this bug (see comment #38) https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=2253

Comment: I have built the latest version of libjingle from trunk, But it does not help.

Comment: there is no fix for this yet. You can follow (star) the bug to know when a fix becomes available.

Comment: Looks like chrome needs sdes crypto key but you are it with providing dtls fingerprint.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was fixed by adding constraint to creation of Peerconnection object.

```
DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement:true


pc = factory.createPeerConnection(iceServers, constraints, pcObserver);
```

where **constraints** has **DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement:true** key value.